# jQuery UI datepicker (in HTML) : How using monthNames instead of monthNamesShort?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am quite new to jQuery and I know the answer has already been answered here :
[jQuery UI datepicker: How to change the month names in the drop-down from short to long names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294232/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-to-change-the-month-names-in-the-drop-down-from-short) but it doesn't sit about what I want.
The question is quite simple : How can I use monthNames instead of monthNamesShort in the datepicker. (I can modifiate the language file but I don't want to (because later the user of my site would be able to choose between short or full month names))
I give you some code if you would like some :

> Javascript :

```
datepicker.regional[ "en-GB" ] = {
closeText: "Done",
prevText: "Prev",
nextText: "Next",
currentText: "Today",
monthNames: [ "January","February","March","April","May","June",
"July","August","September","October","November","December" ],
monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
"Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
dayNames: [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ],
dayNamesShort: [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ],
dayNamesMin: [ "Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa" ],
weekHeader: "Wk",
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
firstDay: 1,
isRTL: false,
showMonthAfterYear: false,
yearSuffix: "" };
datepicker.setDefaults( datepicker.regional[ "en-GB" ] );
```

> Template (HTML):

```
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,showOtherMonths: true,selectOtherMonths: true});
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker("option","monthNames","dateFormat","yy-mm-dd","firstDay",1);
```

You can also give me an idea to use dayNames instead of default dayNamesMin. (deleting for example monthNamesShort doesn't work and show default one and not en-GB charged one)
If you know the syntax to change the default (prefered in the HTML), any help would be welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown list of months uses  `monthNamesShort` by default so you need to replace it by `monthNames`.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/11792/)

```
$.datepicker.regional[ "en-GB" ] = {
        closeText: "Done",
        prevText: "Prev",
        nextText: "Next",
        currentText: "Today",
        monthNames: [ "January","February","March","April","May","June",
        "July","August","September","October","November","December" ],
        monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
        dayNames: [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ],
        dayNamesShort: [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ],
        dayNamesMin: [ "Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa" ],
        weekHeader: "Wk",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: "" };
      $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "en-GB" ] ); 

    var fullmonthnames =  $.datepicker.regional[ "en-GB" ].monthNames;
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[ "en-GB" ] );

          $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
              monthNamesShort: fullmonthnames,
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              showOtherMonths: true,
              selectOtherMonths: true
             });
```

Comment: That's not the answer expected, it is quite difficult and it is not in HTML. Are you sure there is no other issue?

Comment: It seems doing what I want thx. I just wonder how can I swich between monthNames and monthNamesShort. Is there no other way without using the var fullmonthnames?